# How I can test if user have permission for view

Tags: python, django, testing, django-rest-framework

I created permission for my view, and its work but I dont know how I can test if patch request will work with user without permission.

#permission.py

```
class IsObjectCreator(permissions.BasePermission):

def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
    if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
        return True
    return request.user == obj.user
```

#views.py

```
class TaskDetailAPIView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [IsObjectCreator]

    def get_object(self, id):
        try:
            return Task.objects.get(id=id)
        except Task.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404

    def get(self, request, id):
        task = self.get_object(id)
        serializer = TaskSerializer(task)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def patch(self, request, id):
        task = self.get_object(id)
        serializer = StatusSerializer(task, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

In normal Django view I can check if response contain form, but I dont know how in API I can test if response contain patch method.

Answer (score 1):

There's more than one way write permission tests on views in DRF, as described here: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/.
You could use the APIClient to do so, as I roughly describe below:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.test import APIClient
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password

class TaskDetailAPITestCase(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.client = APIClient()
        self.user = User(username='alice', password=make_password('123'),)
        self.task = Task(name="first task", user=self.user)
        self.task.save()

    def test_patch_with_logged_in_user(self):
        self.client.login(username='alice', password='123')
        url = '/tasks/{id}/'.format(id=self.task.id) # change url to match urlpattern.
        response = self.client.patch(self.url, {'name': 'some task'}, format='json')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)

    def test_patch_without_logged_in_user(self):
        url = '/tasks/{id}/'.format(id=self.task.id) # change url to match urlpattern.
        response = self.client.patch(self.url, {'name': 'some task'}, format='json')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)
```

Comment: In my previous view problem was that view worked but I dont know why in my test, status code was always 201 even with user without permission but in view everything worked fine and when I tried do get access to view with user without permission then patch method didn't show. Spliting my custom view on 2 generics views solved problem but I don't know where was problem

Comment: Aha. Would it make a difference if you declared the permission class on the API view like this: `permission_classes = (IsObjectCreator,)` instead of this: `permission_classes = [IsObjectCreator]`?

Comment: I have seen both types to write permission but I really dont know what is diffrence, I thought both have same effect. Permission worked because user without permission didn't have access to patch method so I'm not sure if this could cause problem, maybe I will check this in future because today solving this problem was so annoying that I don't want to back to this again :) And in the end I think that splitting this custom view on 2 generic views is even better.

Answer (score 0):

I sloved problem, i just splited my view on 2 generic views one for get and one for patch and use for this generic views.

```
#api_views

class TaskDetailAPIView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = Task.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TaskSerializer


class TaskUpdateStatusAPIView(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    queryset = Task.objects.all()
    serializer_class = StatusSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsOwnerOrReadOnly]
```

then I wrote this tests:

```
#api_tests

class TaskUpdateStatusAPI(APITestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.client = APIClient()
        self.user = User.objects.create_user(username='test', password='test123')
        self.user2 = User.objects.create_user(username='test2', password='test123')
        user = self.user2
        Task.objects.create(name='Task for test', user=user, status='New', date=date(2019, 4, 9),
                        description='This is description for test purposes')

    def test_access_unauthenticated_user(self):
        task = Task.objects.get(id=1)
        login = self.client.login()
        data = {"status": "DONE"}
        response = self.client.post(reverse('edit_status', kwargs={'pk': task.id}), data, format='json')
        self.assertFalse(login)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 405, f'expected Response code 405, instead get {response.status_code}')

    def test_access_authenticated_user_without_permission(self):
        task = Task.objects.get(id=1)
        login = self.client.login(username='test', password='test123')
        data = {"status": "DONE"}
        response = self.client.post(reverse('edit_status', kwargs={'pk': task.id}), data, format='json')
        self.assertTrue(login)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 405, f'expected Response code 405, instead get {response.status_code}')

    def test_access_authenticated_user_with_permission(self):
        task = Task.objects.get(id=1)
        login = self.client.login(username='test2', password='test123')
        data = {"status": "DONE"}
        response = self.client.post(reverse('edit_status', kwargs={'pk': task.id}), data, format='json')
        self.assertTrue(login)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 405, f'expected Response code 405, instead get {response.status_code}')
```

Comment: You should try PYTEST, also your code doesn't follow DRY